# heap array - remove the root

Tags: java, arrays, heap

I am a bit confused about heaps. I have got an integer array as an implementation of minimum heap. How can you compute the steps of bubbling down when you remove the min item from the root. More importantly, say you've got

```
          3
      5       5
   7    8
```

If you remove 3 then you ll have to replace it with 8 and bubble down. However, as both of the root children have equal value (5) then which way it's gonna bubble down (right ot left)? It's important as the number of steps to put it in order will differ.

Thanks

Comment: I might not be up on heaps, but how can both children be equal value?

Comment: Just depends on your algorithm implementation. You can always guarantee O(logn) on a worst case.

Comment: it is allowed. The only requirement is that they need to be less then the root.

Comment: yeah but in one case you would have one step more. How's that decided??

Comment: it is completely decided by the algorithm you use

Comment: In *this* scenario it is one step more for the left bubble down. That's not always the case. Construct a larger heap with the children being the same, and you can easily rearrange values to show that going right would take more time.

Comment: How can `5` be less than `3` AND greater than `3` at the same time?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's a heap, not a BST.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on your algorithm implementation. Removing the first item is often used in heap-sort algorithm. You take out the first element and put the last element in its place. Then you call `heapify()` on the root which decides which way to bubble down.

```
void heapify(int index) {

        int l = getLeft(index);
        int r = getRight(index);
        int largest;

        if(l <= storage.length && storage[index] < storage[l]){
            largest = l;
        } else {
            largest = index;
        }

        if(r <= storage.length  && storage[largest] < storage[r]){
            largest = r;
        }

        if(largest != index){
            storage.swap(index, largest);
            heapify(largest);
        }

    }
```

You can see that it takes the largest of its children, swap itself and the largest, and keep bubbling down where the largest was. In this implementation if right and left are equal, it will travel the left subtree.

The running time of heapify() on the subtree of size `n` is O(1) to find the largest element + the running time of recursive heapify on the subtree - each subtree has size at most 2n/3, the worst case occurs when the bottom level of the tree is exactly half full.

Therefore the running time of heapify can be described as:

`T(n) = T(2n/3) + O(1)`

by Master Theorem we get that:

`T(n) = O(lg n)`